# roulette - javascript - links

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, html5-canvas, href

I am working on a website where I need a roulette.
I chose this one.

[Creating a Roulette Wheel Using HTML5 Canvas](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-roulette-wheel-using-html5-canvas)

My problem is that I can not get the text to become a link.

I have tried example.

```
var str = "link";
document.write(str.link("page2"));
```

I think the problem is that the text is already in a variable?

But I can not get it to work :/

Some good suggestions? I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: are you trying to use jquery's .link() function?  if so str is not a valid jquery object.

Comment: so it is impossible to do? I am new to JavaScript so I do not know how to get the text clickable - I do not know what way to go ...

Comment: var str. is only one example - if you go in two
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-roulette-wheel-using-html5-canvas # comment-11861
kan see the javascript code I'm talking about

Answer (score 0):

To create a link, you must write out the HTML form of the element:

```
document.write( '<a href="page2">link</a>' );
```

Though it's not good to use `document.write` in real code, so here is an alternative using `document.createElement` and setting attributes to it:

```
var link = document.createElement('a'); // create an anchor element

link.href = "page2"; // set the href

link.innerHTML = "link"; // set the text

document.body.appendChild( link ); // append the element to the body element
```

Comment: I've tried to do what you say, but I'm pretty new to JavaScript so will you might help me to get it to fit with the codes listed on the page?

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-roulette-wheel-using-html5-canvas

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by make the text a link? I'm assuming you mean have each of the roulette wheel options become clickable?
Also, you won't be able to do this using normal methods (eg by changing the line `var text = restaraunts[i];` to `var text = "<a href="link">"+restaraunts[i]+"</a>";` (which might have been the road you were taking with whatever you meant by `var str = "link"; document.write(str.link("page2"));`. You really need to provide some more information

Comment: yes that is exactly what I mean. so you can click and get to another page

but do you think it is all to be done?
it will still not work

Comment: I'm sorry I was not more specific - Im new to JavaScript

Comment: how would you make the text clickable? it might be easier to make each box in the roulette clickable as if a div was display: block;???